# How do you show the back of a device in Visio networking objects?

Tags: visio

I am diagramming a network layout, the wiring in a cabinet, from switch to san.  But I can't find a way to look at the back side of the stock shapes.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [visiocafe.com](http://visiocafe.com), they do front and back templates for the majority of professional hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I would show both front and back of the cabinets (maybe one cabinet per page, so in essence two images) and use the corresponding icon for the front and back. It is more work, of course, but it will give you a very detailed view of the cabling. You can control whether a cable connects to a specific port on the back or front. This is what a lot of network documentation people do for proper visualization of rack diagrams and cabling.

For the icons, as the poster below, try Visio Cafe, and then you also have the specific vendors that provide icons for you to use.